# How to stop recorder of react-mic when parent component is suddenly unmounted and coulldn't change state in time?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-mic, which start/stops recording when a prop of start/stops is passed to it. It's working fine, but in some cases, when a user clicks on some other link in the app while recorder is ON, the parent component of react-mic is unmounted suddenly and I'm not able to update `this.state.record` on time. Since prop is not passed to react-mic, the recording dot is still ON in tab, so can someone suggest me how can I stop the recording or remove the red dot from tab?

```
import { ReactMic } from 'react-mic';

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

    stopRecording = () => {
        this.setState({
          record: false,
        });
    }

    compoentWillUnmount(){
      this.stopRecording()
    }

    render() {

        <ReactMic
            record={this.state.record} // defaults -> false.  Set to 
                                       // true to begin recording
            onStop={this.onStop}       // callback to execute when 
                                       // audio stops recording
            onData={this.onData}
         />
    }
}
```

Not able to stop ReactMic from recording or to remove red dot from top of tab.